# Need distinct values with SUM from multiple tables

Tags: sql, xojo

I'm building a Xojo app and have problems with a query I want to perform.

I need to export a instruction book that is saved in a database

It has 3 tables, one with the pages, one with the Items needed and a Item Database

For now I need to get the results from 2 tables

PartsPerPage and Parts

PartsPerPage

```
ID    -    SetID   -   Page   -   PartID   -   Parts
1     -    1       -   1      -   37878    -   5
2     -    1       -   1      -   23444    -   6
3     -    1       -   1      -   34534    -   11
4     -    1       -   2      -   37878    -   4
```

Parts

```
ID     -   Name   -   Size   -   Image   -   Stock   -   ColorID   -   SortCode
37878  -   Blabla -   6      -   picture -   56      -   12        -   box1
23444  -   Blabla -   9      -   picture -   12      -   11        -   box1
34534  -   Blabla -   3      -   picture -   66      -   101       -   box2
37878  -   Blabla -   2      -   picture -   33      -   4         -   box5
```

Now I want to get a list of all the Items that are used

```
ID     -  Parts  -  Name     -  Size   -  Image    -  ColorID
37878  -  9      -  Blabla   -  6      -  Picture  -  12
23444  -  6      -  Blabla   -  9      -  Picture  -  11  
34534  -  11     -  Blabla   -  3      -  Picture  -  101
```

I've tried some Sql queries but without any success

This one gave me only one record but should be like 155 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     PartsPerPage.PartID, 
     SUM(PartsPerPage.Parts), 
     Parts.Name,
     Parts.Discription, 
     Parts.Size, Parts.image, 
     Parts.ColorID 
FROM PartsPerPage JOIN Parts ON Parts.ID = PartsPerPage.PartID 
WHERE PartsPerPage.SetID = 1
```

When I just do a simple query, Then I'll get 155 records if i do a record count, but not getting the results

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     PartsPerPage.PartID
FROM PartsPerPage
WHERE PartsPerPage.SetID = 1
```

Any Help would be great

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you intend:

```
SELECT ppp.PartID, 
       SUM(PartsPerPage.Parts), 
       p.Name, p.Discription, p.Size, p.image, p.ColorID 
FROM PartsPerPage ppp JOIN
     Parts p
     ON p.ID = ppp.PartID 
WHERE ppp.SetID = 1
GROUP BY ppp.PartID, p.Name, p.Discription, p.Size, p.image, p.ColorID;
```

The `GROUP BY` is needed because you have a `SUM()`.  The `SUM()` turns your query into an aggregation query -- with no `GROUP BY`, exactly one row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `GROUP BY` clause

```
SELECT
     PartsPerPage.PartID, 
     SUM(PartsPerPage.Parts), 
     Parts.Name,
     Parts.Discription, 
     Parts.Size, Parts.image, 
     Parts.ColorID 
FROM PartsPerPage JOIN Parts ON Parts.ID = PartsPerPage.PartID 
WHERE PartsPerPage.SetID = 1
GROUP BY PartsPerPage.PartID;
```